# Can I use a plain VGA to Component converter to connect to a TV?

Tags: vga, tv, components

I bought a [VGA to Component cable converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Y7T5UU).

[image]

Would this work to connect my Windows 7 PC to my TV (it has the standard input I use for the Wii), or do I need some kind of "smart" converter?

Answer (score 4):

If the video card you have supports TV out over VGA, then yes... you can use it.  From that product page...

> Your VGA card must support TV out directly through VGA port function

Not every video card supports this feature.  If your video card does not support TV out through VGA, then you need an actual scan converter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CJOLBW) to convert VGA to composite.

**EDIT**

Ok.  The computer is a Windows 7 PC.  You still need to look up the product page for the specific video card that is in that computer (or integrated video chipset) in order to know if it supports TV out over VGA.  That, or you need to edit your question again to supply that exact information here so we can look it up for you.

Comment: Do you know how to tell if the computer supports this? And do you know how to tell if a macbook does?

Comment: So... you have a Macbook with a Mini DVI port?  You would need one of these http://www.amazon.com/Apple-Mini-dvi-To-Video-Adapter/dp/B00011KHTW to output to Composite video.  Otherwise, you would need to look up the product specifications on the video card you want to connect that cable you purchased.  So, for newer macbooks you don't need a scan converter, you just need the correct mini dvi cable.

Comment: @Thr4wn maybe you should edit your question to include all the details of the system you want to do this with... things like "I have a 2007 Macbook" are important to getting the right information.  Apple hasn't used a VGA port on a notebook since 2001.

Comment: I edited the question. The macbook question was a different question than the original question. I didn't mean to confuse people by asking that in the comments. My apologies.